# 2D Heat Map using matplot lib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm new to python please so bear with me:

I'v been tryin to plot a 2D Heat-Map, similar to the one shown here:

http://mips.helmholtz-muenchen.de/plant/static/images/A_thal_LTRs.png

using the contourf or the colorbar classes, but it just doesnt seem to work.

im using two very simple data-sets as showen in the code: 
`

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

abundance = [0.2,0.3,0.25,0.05,0.05,0.04,0.06]

grain_size = [200,100,70,50,10,5,1]
```

`

i would like the grain_size array to be my x_axis (on a logarithmic scale) and my colors to represent the abundance corresponding with each grain_size (so 0.2 corresponds with 200, 0.3 corresponds with 100 etc...)

so i know i need to normalize my abundance array to fit to a color-bar, but then what?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want ?

```
import matplotlib.cm as cm

ab = np.array(abundance)
gs = np.array(grain_size)
ab_norm = ab/ab.max()*100
plt.matshow([ab_norm], cmap=cm.gist_rainbow_r) 
plt.xticks(range(7), gs)
plt.yticks(range(1), ["abundance"])
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image: ab]

You can change colormap by choosing another one, [see here for some of them](http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html).

Tell me if it's not that, and if you don't understand something.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes precisly! can you add a color bar to it? and change the color? and change to x_axis to be log?

Comment: thamks a lot! great! @jeanjrc how can i set the color bar to refer to the abundance array?

Comment: @Nimrodshn : What do you mean ?

Comment: meaning if you look at the colorbar its showing colors from 0-100 when it should show 0.02-0.3 even though the colors themselves correspond like i would imagine. meaning from grain size 1-50 the colors are more blue whereas going up to 200 they become more red and then green as i would imagine from the data.

Comment: @Nimrodshn then you don't want it to be normalized. So just replace `[ab_norm]` with `[abundance]` in `plt.matshow([...])`

Comment: thanks a lot! do you know how to make the x_axis logarithimic?

Comment: I did not understand that point too, as you have discrete value on your x-axis, which are not log.

Comment: Well this example is a simplified example for a much larger data set with a lot more than 7 entries(around 90, varied from 0-2000 so i wanted to x axis to be set as a logarithmic (e.g 10^0,10^1,10^2,...) and again - i thank you for your time.

Comment: Then, take a look at LogNorm : http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/pcolor_log.html